# Spark-sql CLI use only 1 executor when running query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am going to use spark-sql cli to replace the hive cli shell, and I run the spark-sql cli with following the command,(We are using on yarn Hadoop cluster, the hive-site.xml already copied to /conf)

.> spark-sql
Then the shell is opened and works ok,

And I execute a query something like,

./spark-sql>select devicetype, count(*) from mytable group by devicetype;

The command execute successfully and the result is correct. But I notice the performance is very slow.

From the spark job ui, http://myhost:4040, I noticed that only 1 Executor marked  used, so that’s maybe the reason.

And I try to modify the spark-sql script and add the –num-executors 500 in the exec command, but it does not help.

So anyone could help and explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

`spark-sql` is an SQL CLI tool that works only in local mode, that is why you see only one executor

If you want to have a cluster version of SQL, you should start `thriftserver` and connect to it via JDBC using `beeline` tool (that goes with Spark), for example. You can find the description in chapter ***Running the Thrift JDBC/ODBC server*** of the official documentation http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

To start:

```
export HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT=<listening-port>
export HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_BIND_HOST=<listening-host>
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
  --master <master-uri> \
  ...
```

To connect:

```
./bin/beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://<listening-host>:<listening-port>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  
I tried and see beeline using M/R job to run the sql and not the spark job. And what I want is using spark to run the job. So there's no way to do this for now?

Comment: First, are you sure that you have started thrift server to work with Spark? `start-thriftserver.sh` should be located in Spark directory. Second, are you sure you've specified the right port in beeline and didn't connect to Hive? Just to be sure, I'd recommend you to stop Hive thriftserver if it is running on the same machine

Comment: Our users are not willing to migrate to use beeline, they used to use hive query before, since spark-sql is good to compatible with hive, so I have to back to spark-sql. I see when type spark-sql --help, it say there's parameters like –num-executors, given it's only could worked in local mode why it's has this but could not work?

Comment: You miss the point. "Spark-sql" tool is for debugging purpose only, not for production usage. With Spark Thrift server you bring up something like DBMS engine - a cluster of Spark + JDBC interface. After that your users can use any tool to connect to it (Squirrel, for instance), you are not obligated to use beeline. And they can directly use HiveQL there

Comment: actually user could add --master yarn to launch yarn client mode

Answer (score 0):

beeline

`\> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10002/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice`

10002 is my port for the spark thrift server.

change it to yours.
you can find your thrift port from your thrift log.