# Spark SQL - Not using all the vCores available

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running set of spark-sql queries in parallel using Google dataproc. I am spinning up my own cluster and ideally it should consume all the resources available in the cluster. I do see that number of vCores used is only 40 though 320 vCores are available. Do you know how I can tune the performance in this case?

I tried with different number of cores and executors. Though some apps are pending, it doesn't seem to take additional resources. I am spinning up a cluster of 20 nodes but it is still taking lot of time for computation.

I am setting the number of partitions as 50 to restrict the number of output files. Even if I skip setting it, it doesn't seem to improve performance

Comment: What command did you use to launch spark?

Comment: I have a file with queries. I am using spark-sql -f command to execute.

Comment: For example, how many executors and cores?

Comment: With 10 executor cores, you can use around 32 executors if you have 320 vcores available.

Comment: Should I set spark.executor.instances also to 32 then?

Comment: I tried to set the number of executor instances. Even then I see that only 40 vCores are used.

Comment: Can someone help please? I am not able to increase the number of cores how much ever I try. Many cores are free but still it is running with less than 10% number of cores.

Comment: Please copy paste the full command line you are using to submit the job.

Comment: spark-sql --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=50 spark.executor.cores=4 spark.executor.instances=15 spark.executor.memory=5g spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=4 spark.app.name=pof --hiveconf hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true --hiveconf mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true --> I was setting cores as 4 to see if it is taking 4 core at every instance.

Comment: This question may be of assistance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080673/spark-sql-cli-use-only-1-executor-when-running-query