# How to use Airflow SparkSQLOperator?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I'd like to run a query using Spark SQL in Airflow, it looks like the SparkSQLOperator is perfect for this (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_sql_operator.py) 
However, I can't figure out how the connection must be configured.

In DB Visualizer, I can connect to the Hive database using:

```
driver : jdbc
database url : jdbc:hive2://myserver.com:10000/default
database userid : me
database password : mypassword
```

Applying these settings to the spark_sql_default connection gives me:

> enter[2017-12-12 11:35:33,774] {models.py:1462} ERROR - Cannot execute
>   on hive2://myserver.com:10000/default. Error code is: 1. Output: ,
>   Stderr:

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with Spark or the operator...but I did notice that the ``SparkSqlHook`` (used by ``SparkSqlOperator``) doesn't actually make use of the [connection object](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_sql_operator.py#L72), except in an error message. The operator does have a [master](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_sql_operator.py#L38-L39) parameter, but I think that might be something else.

Comment: Digging around, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111876/1969152 might be relevant. It sounds like you should be using `beeline` or a similar tool instead of `spark-sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Spark isn't a database, so you configure your Spark connection just like you would if you were submitting regular Spark jobs, rather than the JDBC-like parameters you're used to.

If you look at the signature of the operator:

```
def __init__(self,
             sql,
             conf=None,
             conn_id='spark_sql_default',
             executor_cores=None,
             executor_memory=None,
             keytab=None,
             master='yarn',
             name='default-name',
             num_executors=None,
             yarn_queue='default',
             *args,
             **kwargs)
```

You need to create a connection (see models.Connection) that specifies the Spark master, which would be one of 'yarn', 'local[x]', or 'spark://hostname:port'. That should really be it, since they default the rest for you and it is likely handled by the underlying Spark config.

Your SQL or HQL code/script can be passed into the first parameter.

Comment: We use yarn in our company so I used 'yarn' as conn_id, but got error message: 'airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `yarn` isn't defined'. Is there anything else I should specify?

Comment: conn_id is a string that is just the Connection object's name. If you look in your Admin->Connections tab on the web UI, you'll see there's a "spark_default" connection, I think the master is set to "yarn" by default. Your conn_id would then be "spark_default".